# Conservative systems (Strogatz - Non-linear dynamics and chaos)

Tags: dynamical-systems, nonlinear-system

I'm reading a book on Non-linear dynamics by Steven Strogatz and I came across an example in the Conservative Systems' chapter.

The question given is:

Consider a particle of mass m=1 moving in a double-well potential **V(x) = -$\frac{1}{2}$$\ x^2$ + $\frac{1}{4}$$\ x^4$**. Find and classify all the equilibrium points for the system.

Since V(x) = -$\frac{1}{2}$$\ x^2$ + $\frac{1}{4}$$\ x^4$, we differentiate the potential to get the force and obtain F(x) = $\ x$ - $\ x^3$.

We also know that:

> $\ m$ $\ddot x$ = F(x)

Therefore, as $\ m$ = 1;

> $\ddot x$ = $\ x$ - $\ x^3$.

---

Now, that's the part I don't understand. In the book, it says that the last equation can be rewritten as the vector field

$\dot x$ = $\ y$

$\dot y$ = $\ x$ - $\ x^3$.

Where does the

> $\ y$ and $\dot x$ = $\ y$

come from ?

Answer (score 2):

It is a common trick. A new variable $y$ is introduced to transform the second order ODE into two first order ODEs, because it is easier to deal with.

Comment: But, would it make any difference if I said $\dot x$ = $\ x$ - $\ x^3$ instead of $\dot x$ = y?

Comment: You will obtain a different ODE if you said $\dot{x} = x-x^3$. You need to obtain $\ddot{x} = x-x^3$, which can be done replacing $\dot{y}$ in the first equation.